# Who initiated the removal of the Robert E. Lee statue in Charlottesville?

Tags: united-states, protests, monuments

Who initiated the removal of the Robert E. Lee statue in Charlottesville? Any person or group of people who officially initiated the removal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with politics

Comment: The decision to remove the statue was a political process of the city council, and so on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In March 2016, Charlottesville's vice mayor Wes Bellamy held a rally by the statue during which he called on on Charlottesville City Council to remove it and rename Lee Park.

A commission, set up by the city council (named the Blue Ribbon Commission on Race, Monuments and Public Spaces) recommended in Nov. 2016 removing the Lee statue to McIntire Park.

The City Council decided in April 2017 to remove the statue completely. The five council members voted Ayes: Mr. Bellamy, Ms. Szakos, Mr. Fenwick; Noes: Ms.Galvin, Mr. Signer